# Need help simplifying a SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql

The 2 queries at the end of this code return the data that I want.  I'm just wondering if it can be done in 1 query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [TimeStamp] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Person] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnA] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnB] [varchar](1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
     
INSERT Test VALUES('2019-10-01', 'Bill', 'Y', 'N')
INSERT Test VALUES('2019-10-01', 'Joe', 'N', 'Y')
INSERT Test VALUES('2019-10-02', 'Bill', 'Y', 'Y')
INSERT Test VALUES('2019-10-03', 'Bill', 'Y', 'Y')
INSERT Test VALUES('2019-10-04', 'Joe', 'Y', 'Y')
 
SELECT COUNT(ColumnA) AS ColumnACount 
FROM Test 
WHERE ColumnA = 'Y' AND Person = 'Bill'

SELECT COUNT(ColumnB) AS ColumnBCount 
FROM Test 
WHERE ColumnB = 'Y' AND Person = 'Bill'
```

The query should return 2 columns, `ColumnACount` and `ColumnBCount`, with values 3 and 2, respectively.

Comment: I'm thinking you can use SUM(Case ) for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when ColumnA = 'Y' then 1 end) AS ColumnACount,
       COUNT(case when ColumnB = 'Y' then 1 end) AS ColumnBCount
FROM Test
WHERE Person = 'Bill' and 'Y' in (ColumnA, ColumnB)
```

The `'Y' in (ColumnA, ColumnB)` isn't really needed, but may speed things up.